# How do I define one-to-many relationships across different XSD Files, and why does xs:extends not work in this situation?

Tags: xsd, visual-studio-2012, one-to-many

I have been developing some xml schema files over the past few days, and learned of a specific element to extend simpletypes and complextype elements.

I am currently using the visual studio 2012 professional edition, and I am currently testing relationships of XSD files (I daresay parent-child relationships , or one to many relationships) between these files, for example (I am using objects from Google DFA API):

```
RichMediaAsset
∟ RichMediaExpandingHtmlAsset
∟ RichMediaExpandingHtmlAsset
∟ RichMediaFloatingHtmlAsset
...
```

All these classes "extend" or "Inherit" from RichMediaAsset (which is the base, or abstract). I have defined RichMediaAsset as the following in XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema id="RedirectCreativeBase" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <!-- simpleTypes=primitive -->
  <!-- extBooleanMethodPrefix=is -->
  <xs:complexType name="RichMediaAssetWrapper" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="fileName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="fileSize" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="parentAssetId" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I have defined the second file, RichMediaExpandingHtmlAsset as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="RichMediaExpandingHtmlAssetWrapper" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="./RichMediaAsset.xsd"/>
  <xs:complexType name="RichMediaExpandingHtmlAssetWrapper" abstract="false" >
    <xs:extension base="RichMediaAssetWrapper"> <!-- Not happy here -->
      <xs:sequence>
         <!-- content to be included,extending RichMediaAsset's complex type called RichMediaAssetWrapper -->
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The part which I mentioned VS2012 is not happy with is defined as follows:

```
Warning 1   The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:extension' element is not supported in this context.  C:\eclipse\Workspace\aem_adservices_google_dfa\aem.adservices.google.dfa\xsd\Creative\RichMediaExpandingHtmlAsset.xsd   5   6   Miscellaneous Files
Warning 2   The element 'complexType' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' has invalid child element 'extension' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'. List of possible elements expected: 'annotation, simpleContent, complexContent, group, all, choice, sequence, attribute, attributeGroup, anyAttribute' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.    C:\eclipse\Workspace\aem_adservices_google_dfa\aem.adservices.google.dfa\xsd\Creative\RichMediaExpandingHtmlAsset.xsd   5   6   Miscellaneous Files
```

The question now: Is this a possible bug of 2012, have I made an error, is this simply not supported (even though I checked the usage examples at w3schools.com), or is there better ways for me to define the one to many relationships?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with my XSD. It was in fact missing a tag. In these cases, `xs:complexContent` or `xs:simpleContent` must be defined in order to  define extensions or restrictions on a complex/simple type respectively that contains mixed content or elements only.

Here is my solution, and the errors in my code also disappeared.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="RichMediaExpandingHtmlAssetWrapper" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="./RichMediaAsset.xsd"/>
  <xs:complexType name="RichMediaExpandingHtmlAssetWrapper" abstract="false" >
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="RichMediaAssetWrapper">
        <xs:sequence>
          ...
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Sources: [ComplexContent](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_complexcontent.asp); [SimpleContent](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_simpleContent.asp)